# ReactiveRedisTemplate Cache Miss

Tags: spring-data-redis-reactive

How do we handle cache miss scenario using **ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String>**? Also, need to log and treat any error from underlying Redis cache as cache miss.

please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without a code example, but you can utilize the operator `.switchIfEmpty()`. You'll need to defer the Mono so it's lazy loaded and only evaluated after the Redis template returns something.

```
.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> callMethodToFetchData());
```

Comment: Thanks, switchIfEmpty is getting invoked on cache miss